# ClickOnce - Publishing folder vs. Installation folder

Tags: clickonce

Could someone tell me the difference between the publishing folder location and the installation folder URL? Is there any reason why these two wouldn't be the same?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You enjoyed my answer in the MSDN Forums so much, I'm posting the [link to the answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/ed62d923-4340-4f3c-b883-42da38985a54) here as well. ;-)

---

If you are publishing and installing from the same URL, you can just fill in the publishing file location and be done.

The reason there are two is so if you want to publish to one place, but have an installation URL that's different, you can do that.

For example, you might want to publish to your server using ftp, in which case the publishing file location will be `ftp://myserver/myvirtualfolder/myapp` and the installation url might be `http://myserver/myapp`

You might want to publish to a folder on your local disk and do something to the deployment before pushing it to the webserver. In this case, you might publish to `C:\_Publish\MyApp\`, add some files, re-sign the manifest, and copy it to `\inetpub\MyApp\`, and the installation url would be `http://myserver/myapp`

Comment: 'you can just fill in the publish file location'.. as in, don't fill in the install location information? When I began the publishing procedure, it brought up the publishing wizard. (I presume this is how most people will first interact with publishing).. The wizard provided me with 3 radio button options to choose from at the install section. It doesn't indicate that the install directory is optional. (VS2012).

Comment: This still assumes you know the difference between the publishing an installation folders.  I know one is where it's going to be pushed now, and the other is where the app will check for new versions on startup, but I can't remember which is which.