# Publishing software to server

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, publishing

I have a Windows VPS which I want to use to host my application files for my .NET software projects. This is so I can check the handy option in Visual Studio 2012 (Premium Edition) of "The application should check for updates".

However, getting this to work is a nightmare.

There are 2 fields I need to fill in:

[image]

My question is, what is each one looking setting and how should my web server be set up accordingly?

I assume the publishing folder (in red) can point to an FTP site and as such, since I'm using FileZilla, I don't need to configure IIS on my VPS.

Then I have the installation folder (in blue). I assume this must be a URL which is resolvable, therefore will need to be configured in IIS and testable by simply copying this value into a browser.

Are my assumptions about the 2 values correct?

Comment: Check this SO thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639910/clickonce-publishing-folder-vs-installation-folder)

Comment: Yes you need to setup website in IIS and it should be resolvable.

Comment: i posted my comment as answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Publishing folder should point to any ftp location on server where you can copy/publish  code to, Installation folder is location where website is installed/published and can be accessed by a url, you need to setup website in IIS and it should be resolvable

Check this SO thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639910/clickonce-publishing-folder-vs-installation-folder) for more details