# Hide ClickOnce update folder

Tags: c#, clickonce

iam deployng a simply exe app via ClickOnce on our shared folder.

app should be installed on local folder.

to avoid risk i want to hide location of deployed file to user.
i want to share them only location where installer is, all update should be deployed to different folder

how can i do it?

how i have to setup publishing folder and installation folder?

i try to set publish folder

```
\\sharedfolder\App\moreSecretFolder\MyApp
```

and
install fodler as

```
\\SharedFolder\InstallMyApp
```

hoping that user can go to second folder to launch installer and App go to first folder to search for update but don't works in this way: after deploy `InstallMyApp` fodler is empty

Comment: Please see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639910/clickonce-publishing-folder-vs-installation-folder as to the difference between Publishing Folder and Installation URL.  The Installation URL is how your application will be referenced and the Publishing Folder is the location to which you are publishing the deployment.

Comment: i read it before creating question, but don't understand how to apply to my needs so i start this...